# AngularJS checking if a field within an object array exists

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, loops

I have a data model like this:

```
var array =  [{id:1, name:"foo"}, {id:2, name:"bar"}, {id:3 name:"september"}];
```

I want to loop through the array and see if id:3 exists how do i do that?

Comment: I'd say you should loop through the array and see if the `id` property equals `3`

Comment: What aspect of the problem do you have trouble with? Do you understand how to loop over an array?

Comment: @teddybear123 aren't u missing a `,` after `id:3`? updated my answer.

Answer (score 9):

Just use an AngularJS [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter), these are exactly made for that purpose:

```
var results = $filter('filter')(array, {id : 3}, true);
```

`results` will contain an an array of object(s) (there might be more than one) with an attribute `id` equal to `3`.

If the length of `results` is zero then, there was no element matching the filter.
If you know, there is only one possible result you may retrieve it directly with `results[0]`.

The advantage of using a filter is that you can easily filter on multiple attribute values by extending the filter expression `{id : 3}`.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

This is more a js problem than an angular one. If you are using a library like lodash this is pretty straightforward :

```
_.findWhere(array, {'id': 3})
```

In plain javascript this is not much complicated. Here is an EcmaScript 5 solution, that makes use of the function **[some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)** :

```
array.some(function(elem) {
    return elem.id === 3;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Wonder, you are missing a `,` after `id:3`

It's more of a javaScript looping over an Array than an AngularJS way,

```
var array =  [{id:1, name:"foo"}, {id:2, name:"bar"}, {id:3, name:"september"}];

for(var i in array){
    if(array[i].id === 3){
         console.log("found 3");
        //do something here.
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need lodash, even.  Native javascript:

```
(array.filter(function(a) {return a.id === 3})
```

will return an array containing only the element whose id is 3 if there is one, or an empty array if not.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with plain JavaScript:

```
array.find(function(element){
    if(element.id == 3) return true;
})
```

Comment: `find` is an ECMAScript 2015 method, and because of that it has very poor browser support as of now.